# Use Zend_Autoloader for Models

Tags: php, zend-framework, autoloader

does someone knows how to use the "new" Zend Autoloader to Load Models ? In the Moment my Configuration looks like this :

application.ini

```
# Autoloader Namespace
autoloadernamespaces.0 = "Sl_"
```

Bootstrap.php

```
   /**
     * Start Autoloader
     *
     * @access protected
     * @return Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader
     */
    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'Sl_',
            'basePath'  => dirname(__FILE__),
        ));

        return $autoloader;
    }
```

So when I place a Model in /Models/User.php with

```
class Sl_Model_User{}
```

and create an new object , everything works like designed. But how can i use the Autoloader to load a Model placed in /Models/Dao/UserDB.php ?

```
class Dao_UserDB{}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the documentation on the Resource_Autoloader (its purpose is to load resources that reside in the models directory or elsewhere - i.e outside the /library folder).

"Resource autoloaders are intended to manage namespaced library code that follow Zend Framework coding standard guidelines, but which do not have a 1:1 mapping between the class name and the directory structure. Their primary purpose is to facilitate autoloading application resource code, such as application-specific models, forms, and ACLs.

Resource autoloaders register with the autoloader on instantiation, with the namespace to which they are associated. This allows you to easily namespace code in specific directories, and still reap the benefits of autoloading."

```
path/to/some/directory/
    acls/
         Site.php
    forms/
        Login.php
    models/
        User.php


$resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
'basePath'  => 'path/to/some/directory',
'namespace' => 'My',
```

));

```
$resourceLoader->addResourceTypes(array(
'acl' => array(
    'path'      => 'acls/',
    'namespace' => 'Acl',
),
'form' => array(
    'path'      => 'forms/',
    'namespace' => 'Form',
),
'model' => array(
    'path'      => 'models/',
),
```

));

Try this in your boostrap file:

```
protected function _initLoaderResource()
{
    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
        'basePath'  => 'your_doc_root' . '/application',
        'namespace' => 'MyNamespace'
    ));
    $resourceLoader->addResourceTypes(array(
        'model' => array(
            'namespace' => 'Model',
            'path'      => 'models'
        )
    ));
}
```

Comment: Hi, and where to load the Resourceloader ? or can i add this to module loader ?

Comment: Try this in your boostrap file

          protected function _initLoaderResource()
 {
  $resourceLoader = new  Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array('basePath'  => 'path/to/application',
   'namespace' => 'MyNameSpace'
  ));
$resourceLoader->addResourceTypes(
array('model' => array(
    'namespace' => 'Model',
    'path'      => 'models'
   )
  ));
 }

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your current setup

ClassFile:
/Models/Dao/UserDB.php

ClassName:
class Dao_UserDB{}

should be:

```
$autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
    'namespace' => 'Dao_',
    'basePath'  => APPLICATION_ROOT.'/Models/Dao/',
));
```

But you also could name the Class:
S1_Dao_UserDB() this should work without changing.

Answer (score 0):

To define autoloader rules for custom models (in custom library dir) like:

```
|-application
|-library
  |-Foo
    |-Models
      |-Bar.php (holds Foo_Model_Bar class - mind no 's' in class name)
    |-Forms 
      |-Bar.php (holds Foo_Form_Bar class - mind no 's' in class name)
  |-Zend
|-public
|-test
```

You should add this in your Bootstrap.php

```
/**
 * Enable loading custom  classes
 */
public function _initAutoloaders()
{
    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
        'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/Foo',
        'namespace' => 'Foo_'
    ));

    $resourceLoader->addResourceTypes(array(
        'foomodels' => array(
            'namespace' => 'Model_',
            'path' => 'Models')
        ),
        'fooforms' => array(
            'namespace' => 'Form_',
            'path' => 'Forms')
        ),
    );
}
```

Took me a while to figure it out, hope it saves someones time.